# VBA excel, fill every other executed row with a color

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, row

I am having trouble with this part of my code. So far it's correct, but I am required to fill every other row with a color, and all rows with borders

Purpose of full code: everytime the user presses the add item button, the procedure runs, and adds the data row to the following row of a table.

```
If IsNumeric(Quantity) And Quantity >= 1 Then
  While Not IsEmpty(Range("I12").Offset(i, 0))
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  Range("G13").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = item_no
  Range("H13").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = itemDescription
  Range("I13").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = Quantity
  Range("J13").Offset(i - 1, 0).Select
  Selection.Offset(0, 0) = Quantity * itemValue
Else:
  Quantity = False Or Quantity = vbCancel
  QtyError = MsgBox("Please enter a valid purchase quantity!", _
        vbCritical, "Incorrect Purchase Quantity")
End If
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to format the table as such and ask Excel to do the formatting with `.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("I12:I" & 12 + i),, xlYes).Name = "YourTableName"`? Alternatively, you could also use the conditional formatting using a formula to determine the cell format with `=mod(row(), 2)`. Conditional formatting allowed you to change the background color and the border lines even prior to Office 2007+.

Comment: I don't know how to exactly do that, 
I'm a student doing this for a class assignment. 

I'm not sure how to incorporate i in =mod(row(), 2).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I am posting the solution using the conditional formatting:

1. Select the cells which you would like to format.
2. Select conditional formatting from the menu.
3. Click on "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter the formula I posted above `=mod(row(), 2)`
5. Make the formatting choices you want and confirm with OK.

[image]

Note, if you record your actions with the Excel macro recorder then you can also incorporate the VBA code into your program.

Comment: I have a table, that adds items the user inputs, every time the user inputs an item number, a new raw of data is added to the table, and so on. I'm trying to make every other row that is added to the table yellow

Comment: This solution makes every other row blue. You may certainly change it to be yellow in your case.